# Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin supported Firefox versions

Tags: gwt, firefox-addon

How can I find which version of Firefox does the Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin support ? I can't find it anywhere.

As Firefox now has it small development cycle, it could be nice if Google point us to a page where we could find the supported browsers versions.

*For information :
I'm using Firefox version 5.0 with no problem.
I saw on Google Groups people saying that the version 8.0 works too.
Actual version of Firefox is 11.*

**EDIT 1 :**

Last supported version can be found here http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/plugins/xpcom/prebuilt/update.rdf as suggested by Thomas.

```
<em:minVersion>3.0</em:minVersion>
<em:maxVersion>16.0.*</em:maxVersion>
```

**EDIT 2 :**
The file pointed in EDIT 1 do not seems to exist anymore, so the best shot it looking at the commits logs, here : https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/list

ex:

> r11637         update for Firefox 23 / Mac
>
> r11636         update for Firefox 23 on Windows

Comment: More info about plugins you can look at http://pluginsarena.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DevMode plugin supports all versions of Firefox from 3.0 to 11.0: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/plugins/xpcom/prebuilt/update.rdf

There's always some lag after a Firefox version is released, but a preliminary version of the DevMode plugin is generally available "unofficially" from the GWT Google Groups a few days (or even hours) after the Firefox release, pending code review before it graduates to the SVN repository. The problem is that the plugin has to be recompiled against the updated Gecko SDK, which is released a few hours or days after Firefox.

…and then the http://gwt.google.com/missing-plugin/ also lags a few days/hours behind (it hasn't yet been updated for Firefox 11 at the time I write), but the plugin for Firefox 11 can be [downloaded from the SVN repository](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/plugins/xpcom/prebuilt/gwt-dev-plugin.xpi).

Comment: Seems legit. However they could put somewhere the compatibility status with the current version. I'm marking your answer as accepted, as it explains very well the problem. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla is hiding their ftp server with "old" releases pretty good.

Here is the URL: ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/11.0/

Comment: Probably they want most users to use the latest version. But they are not "hiding" it, the official support forum mentions it as well: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/960454

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking more infomation about how to install/remove/features of the google plugin,

you can look at [google plugin tutorial](http://pluginsarena.com/google-update-plugin/)